# replace empty fields with string in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following table loaded onto Pig using the CSVloader:

```
list = LOAD '/user/department_list.csv' USING CSVLoader(',') AS (employee_name:chararray, city:chararray, department:chararray, joining_year:chararray);

"HENRY, JOHN", DALLAS, SALES, 2020

"JANE STEVENS", AUSTIN, ACCOUNTING 2019

"ALEX SILVA", MIAMI,,2021

...
```

I would like to find and replace any empty department (like in case of Alex) with 'not decided'.

I tried using the following code but it leaves the field empty as well:

```
list2 = foreach list GENERATE employee_name, city, (department IS NOT NULL ? department:'not decided') as department, joining_year;
```

Thanks!

Comment: list2 = foreach list GENERATE employee_name, city, (department IS NOT NULL OR department == '' ? department:'not decided') as department, joining_year;

? 

Could be that the field is actually not null and is actually an empty string?

Comment: Thank you saph_top! You are right, the field was an empty chararray. I was able to find and replace using:

list2 = foreach list GENERATE employee_name, city, (department !='' ? department: 'not decided') as department, joining_year;